# Simple Image Quiz Quandry: Next Button Triggers a New Full Screen Image

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, radio-button

I'm trying to design some multiple choice/image quizzes for a local art school I run.  I can't, however, find adequate examples of what I am trying to do - certainly not by any quiz generators which all appear to have been designed in 1997.

I prefer the simplicity of the posted quiz code but can't figure out how to make the "Next Question" trigger a new full screen image.  Despite library JavaScript books and endless Google searches regarding image arrays and radio buttons, I must concede defeat and admit that I am out of my element.  So here I am, pleading for some code charity - all in the name of art education.

Ideally, the "Next Question" Button would trigger a different full screened background image of a famous painting.  The quiz/text would appear on top of said image, stating something like:

"This painters work shocked Parisians when it was first shown in the Salon des Refuses of 1863" followed by a few multiple choice answers, such as:

Edgar Degas/Edouard Manet /James Whistler

Any help would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/theandyman/9HNGD/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Image Quiz</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/quizandbackgroundimg.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<img alt="full screen background image" src="images/balloons.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 

<div id="container">
<h1>Quiz app</h1>
<p>There will be no points awarded for unanswered questions.</p>
<div id="content">
<h3 id="question"></h3>
<div id="choices"></div>
<p><button id="submit"></button></p>
<p id="score"></p>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/quiz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(JavaScript can be viewed at the JSFiddle Link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the image to the quiz array like so:

```
var quiz = [{
  "question": "The first question doesn't seem to be showing?",
  "choices": ["Don't", "Know", "Why"],
  "correct": "Why",
  "image": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f4/The_Scream.jpg/475px-The_Scream.jpg"
}, ...]
```

Then add a line in the askQuestion function that swaps out the src attribute of the image based on the image set in the array above:

```
$("full-screen-background-image").src = quiz[currentQuestion].image;
```

I've knocked up a quick JSFiddle based on the code you provided http://jsfiddle.net/69BPA/

Comment: You rock gazw!!!!  I can't thank you enough!!  Really and truly, this is going to help out a lot of budding artists. - Andrew from the Art School of Salem (http://artschoolofsalem.com/)

Comment: Hi gazw, so I've created a few quizzes with the code above (http://artschoolofsalem.com/quizzes.html), but as you can see, the art images load slowly.  Is there any way to have an array of full screen images that load faster?  The images were saved with gray bars on either side so as not to cut off the artwork in full screen. In order to reduce image size, is there a way to make the background gray while sizing the image to stretch vertically or horizontally depending on its greatest width/height so that nothing gets cut off?